# Translate GCC inline asm (SSE2, SSSE3) to MSVC intrinsics

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, inline-assembly, sse2

I'm borrowing some code from the VLC to my video player, written in MSVC++ 2010, and cannot find equivalent to its inline asms, related to extracting decoded video frame from the GPU memory to the conventional memory.
Particularly, I don't know how to translate this instruction:

```
movq   %%xmm1,   8(%[dst1])
```

which can be seen in the function `SplitUV` in the file `vlc/modules/codec/avcodec/copy.c`.

According to MSDN, intrinsics for `movq` are `_mm_move_epi64`, `_mm_loadl_epi64` and `_mm_storel_epi64`. 
However, they require `__m128i` arguments, and if I add 1 to the pointer to `__m128i`, I'll get the offset of 16 bytes, while I need 8 bytes.

The whole assembler code is the following:

```
for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
  asm volatile (
    "movdqu (%[shuffle]), %%xmm7\n"
    "movdqa  0(%[src]), %%xmm0\n"
    "movdqa 16(%[src]), %%xmm1\n"
    "movdqa 32(%[src]), %%xmm2\n"
    "movdqa 48(%[src]), %%xmm3\n"
    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm0\n"
    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm1\n"
    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm2\n"
    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
    "movq   %%xmm0,   0(%[dst1])\n"
    "movq   %%xmm1,   8(%[dst1])\n"
    "movhpd %%xmm0,   0(%[dst2])\n"
    "movhpd %%xmm1,   8(%[dst2])\n"
    "movq   %%xmm2,  16(%[dst1])\n"
    "movq   %%xmm3,  24(%[dst1])\n"
    "movhpd %%xmm2,  16(%[dst2])\n"
    "movhpd %%xmm3,  24(%[dst2])\n"
    : : [dst1]"r"(&dstu[x]), [dst2]"r"(&dstv[x]), [src]"r"(&src[2*x]), 
        [shuffle]"r"(shuffle) 
    : "memory"
 );
 ...
}
```

I've started translating, line by line, and by now have the following code (incomplete):

```
__m128i x0, x1, x2, x3, x7;
__m128i *pshuffle128 = (__m128i *)shuffle;
__m128i *pSrc = (__m128i *)src;

for (x = 0; x < (width & ~31); x += 32) {
    __m128i *dst1 = (__m128i *)dstu + x;
    __m128i *dst2 = (__m128i *)dstv + x; 
    x7 = _mm_loadu_si128(pshuffle128);  //    "movdqu (%[shuffle]), %%xmm7\n"
    x0 = _mm_load_si128(pSrc + 0);      //    "movdqa  0(%[src]),   %%xmm0\n"
    x1 = _mm_load_si128(pSrc + 1);      //    "movdqa 16(%[src]),   %%xmm1\n"
    x2 = _mm_load_si128(pSrc + 2);      //    "movdqa 32(%[src]),   %%xmm2\n"
    x3 = _mm_load_si128(pSrc + 3);      //    "movdqa 48(%[src]),   %%xmm3\n"
    x0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x0, x7);      //    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm0\n"
    x1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x1, x7);      //    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm1\n"
    x2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x2, x7);      //    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm2\n"
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x3, x7);      //    "pshufb  %%xmm7, %%xmm3\n"
    _mm_storel_epi64(dst1 + 0, x0);     //    "movq   %%xmm0,   0(%[dst1])\n"
```

The next instruction would be that

```
movq   %%xmm1,   8(%[dst1])
```

and I don't know how to specify offset of 8 bytes.
Also, I have some doubts that I've correctly translated PSHUFB.

Would be very grateful for comments and suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this stuff, but I believe there are intrinsics that are shared by both compilers, you should aim to use those.

Comment: No, there's no such thing. MSVC for x86 can also use inline asm, but MSVC for x64 - can't.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are 2 errors. (1) I've switched dstu and dstv (2) pSrc must be assigned in the cycle body to the value (__m128i *)(src+2*x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `char*` pointer for `dst` that you can increment by 8 and cast it to `__m128i*` in the call to `_mm_storel_epi64` similar to how it's done [here](http://browse-code.mrpt.org/stable/libs/base/src/utils/CImage_SSE3.cpp) (search for "_mm_storel_epi64" on that page).